# SEO Friendly URL Command in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

I have a dynamic page that looks like the following:

```
www.sitedomain.com/page.php?id=30&name=about_our_company
```

I want to make my website links SEO friendly by having something like the following:

```
www.sitedomain.com/about_our_company.html
```

Or

```
www.sitedomain.com/about_our_company
```

My question is: what regex/code I should have in the .htaccess file?

Thanks

Comment: for more check this, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: In this way you are relying on title, not on the id.

Comment: are you using wordpress?

Comment: This is basis of mod_rewrite.. the Stackoverflow policy says `Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!`

Comment: check this site http://learnwebscripts.com/how-to-create-a-seo-friendly-url-using-htaccess this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ofc has a fixed id of `30`.

```
RewriteRule ^about_our_company/?$  /page.php?name=$1&id=30 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

since `/about_our_company` doesn't include the ID, it's impossible to invent the ID correctly.

the way I do it in my own CMS is to have something like this in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

then in index.php, use the `$_REQUEST['page']` (assuming PHP) variable to find the right page details in the database

Answer (score 0):

You could improve this to be more generic:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$  /page.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

The following URL's would all match:

```
http://example.com/30/about_our_company
http://example.com/29/contact
http://example.com/10/our_work
```